# Featured image size per post type

Tags: post-thumbnails

Hi I have several featured image sizes I need to use throughout the site, some of them pertaining to custom post types. Could I set them in some way so that the image sizes are not created for the featured images of all posts/pages but only to the custom post types where they will actually be used? I want this in order not to bloat the installation with a lot of different sized images. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Checkout this plugin i developed for use in my theme.

http://swiftthemes.com/swiftdynamicthumbs-plugin-to-generate-thumbnails-dynamically-when-needed/

Comment: Great so this works similar to Timthumb then, resizing images when the page loads? Tested the plugin, it still resizes the image according to the WordPress default presets, but does not create the other custom image sizes, neat stuff thanks!